# Prevent having to rotate faces every time I unwrap an object

Tags: texturing, uv

I tend to re-unwrap objects a lot during my workflow / experimentation.

Whenever I add a new object with the same texture, I like to make the texture match the scale of it's siblings, so I unwrap all objects with the same material then scale the textures accordingly.

For example - Making a wood grain follow the length of an object instead of its height.

Unfortunately, whenever I do this, I have to re-rotate the faces of previous siblings.

Is there a way to make the faces stay rotated, so when I unwrap it again the faces stay in the desired orientation?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "Pin" is what I was looking for.

In the UV Editor highlight vertices, edges, or faces you want to pin then:

`Right Click -> Pin`

This keeps the UV's wherever you left them during the last unwrap.